# creating a prepared statement to save values to a database

Tags: java, android, database

Im trying to create a prepared statement so that when i click a button it saves a users username and password to a database for them to be able to login. But i have no idea how to do this. Any pointers? Below is my code:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username, password;
    Button registartion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    }

    private Connection getConnection()
    {

        String host = "jdbc:mysql://jdbc.fmc.me.uk:3306/db_ben";
        String u = "user_ben";
        String p = "********";
        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, u, p);
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean registerUser(){

        //Get username
        EditText regUsernameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
        String regUsernameStr = regUsernameBox.getText().toString();

        //Get password
        EditText regPasswordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
        String regPasswordStr = regPasswordBox.getText().toString();

        System.out.println(regUsernameStr);
        System.out.println(regPasswordStr);

        return false;
    }

    public void buttonClick() {
        final Button registerUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        registerUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                registerUser();
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: start from **not using** jdbc on android

Comment: Why cant i use jdbc on android?

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a example for you. You can set variables on the places where a question mark is in the query string. The index of these start with 1, not 0!

```
String query = "INSERT INTO User (Username, Password) VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, regUsernameStr.toLowerCase());
ps.setString(2, regPasswordStr));
if (ps.executeUpdate() == 1) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Furthermore, you should save the username as all lowercase, so you can check easier when checking the login. And you should allways hash the users password before saving it to the database!

You should not use JDBC on android, as it takes more data to communicate to the server. Best practice is to build a php api, which returns the data you want as JSON. However, if data isn't a big issue for now, you can still use JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.

```
private boolean registerUser(){

    //Get username
    EditText regUsernameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
    String regUsernameStr = regUsernameBox.getText().toString();

    //Get password
    EditText regPasswordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
    String regPasswordStr = regPasswordBox.getText().toString();

    System.out.println(regUsernameStr);
    System.out.println(regPasswordStr);

    int i = 0;
    Connection con = getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, regUsernameStr);
        pst.setString(2,regPasswordStr);
        i = pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(i>0)
         return true;
    return false;
}
```